# How to get days between two different dates in react js inside map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

How to find the difference between the return date and departure date in ReactJs jsx map loop.

**JSON response:**

```
{
    departureDate: '2020-07-28', 
    returnDate: '2020-09-16', 
}
```

**Component**

```
 const DaysDiff = () => {
            const days = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
       return(
         Object.keys(datajson).map((key,index): ReactElement => (

                <h2>{((datajson[key].returnDate) - (datajson[key].departureDate)) / days) } </h2>
    )

     )

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Yahoo I resolved my issue. I updated the answer below.

```
<h2> Math.floor((Date.parse(datajson[key].returnDate) - Date.parse(datajson[key].departureDate)) / days)</h2>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const DaysDiff = () => {
const days = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
return(
    Object.keys(datajson).map((key,index): ReactElement => (
        <h2>{Math.floor(((datajson[key].returnDate) - (datajson[key].departureDate)) / days) )} </h2>
    )
)
}
```